# Xlwings Insert new row with no formatting

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I am using xlwings in python and I am trying to insert a new row that does not copy formatting from adjacent rows. Currently I have:

```
ws.range("4:4").api.Insert(InsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight)
```

According to excel docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) the dafault option for CopyOrigin is xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove and there is no option for no formatting, but it can be achieved using the clear formats method:

```
With Range("B2:E5")
.Insert xlShiftDown
.ClearFormats
```

Above is VB code but I'm not sure how to use the ClearFormats method in python, I have tried:

```
ws.range("4:4").api.Insert(InsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight.ClearFormats)
```

and others ways of adding ClearFormats but cant get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the xlwings api:

```
ws = xw.apps.active.books.active.sheets.active
ws.range('8:8').insert(shift='down', copy_origin='format_from_left_or_above')
ws.range('8:8').clear()  # clears content and formatting
```

- shift - `'down'` or `'right'`
- copy_origin - `'format_from_left_or_above'` or `'format_from_right_or_below'`

---

If you would still like to use the native excel api:

```
ws = xw.apps.active.books.active.sheets.active
ws.range('I:I').api.Insert(Shift=-4161, CopyOrigin=1) # shift right, format from right or below
ws.range('I:I').api.ClearFormats()
```

The respective values for [`Shift`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlinsertshiftdirection) and [`CopyOrigin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlinsertformatorigin) below:

- `Shift` param

```
Name            Value
xlShiftDown     -4121
xlShiftToRight  -4161
```

- `CopyOrigin` param

```
Name                    Value
xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove     0
xlFormatFromRightOrBelow    1
```